# Ruby CGI script startup time

Tags: ruby, performance, time, cgi, startup

I have a Ruby CGI script that I use in my web application. The trouble is, the script is used very often and it is quite big - I load quite a few gems. This results in a long startup time. I know that Ruby 1.9.3 improved startup time, but this is not enough.

What are some of the ways to improve startup time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your script/application to be a [Rack application](http://rack.rubyforge.org/). Once you have done that, you will be able to use Rack's handlers for the faster FCGI or SCGI or other fast CGI handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want good performance, use a persistent server technology, not CGI. CGI is notoriously slow in any language. You need to persist your code on a server to completely eliminate startup time.

I'd check out [Sinatra](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.sinatrarb.com/&ei=MNTrTuuKK6nq0gHM7-jVCQ&usg=AFQjCNFFFKzlCnMagiB-8gN7Iz9xgm7mRg&sig2=td5d-JuSKiu_2SHaGp3RVg), which is every bit as easy to develop for as CGI. Setup can be easy too. There are many server solutions you can use, such as passenger (which is loaded into apache, for example, as mod_passenger, much like mod_cgi). There's even a standalone server built into the Sinatra framework -- super easy.

Comment: Well, Sinatra is good and all when it is an option. PHP is set in stone for the web design part of the project. One extremely cool project that I found - very much in the area of persistence, is MagLev - http://maglev.github.com/.

Comment: You can have the app operate as a service, no web design necessary. This architecture is both more modern and performant.